# How can I return the correct x and y coordinate in relation to an image after scrolling?

Tags: java, image, coordinates, jscrollpane

Edit: I ended up using the following code on my image panel, rather than my scroll panel

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY();
            System.out.println("x: " + x);
            System.out.println("y: " + y);

        }});
```

To solve my problem, thanks to Trobbins

I've got an image that is much bigger than my monitor (5500x3800), thus I need to use a JScrollPane to move around the image. I've set it up so that when I click on the image, it prints out the x coordinate and y coordinate, but when using

```
e.getX(), e.getY()
```

it only gives me the X and Y values relative to the window, not relative to the image.

How can I get the x and y coordinates to be relative to the image?

My idea was to keep track of how far I've scrolled and add that to the x and y values but I don't know how I'd go about doing that

Comment: Try this SO post: [How do I get the X and Y location of an image in a JScrollPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993455/how-do-i-get-the-x-and-y-location-of-an-image-in-a-jscrollpane)

Comment: With some minor changes, this did exactly what I wanted it to. Thank you!

Comment: happy to help! For future reference, all I did was search SO for "x y location mouse image JScrollPane" :)

Comment: FYI, it would be better to add your solution as an answer, rather than editing it into the question.

Comment: @gla3dr It would be better to close the question as a duplicate

Comment: @MadProgrammer That would be even better in this case. I just meant that, in general, it's the preferred course of action when you find the solution to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Point p = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewPosition();
int imageX = event.getX() + p.x;
int imageY = event.getY() + p.y;
```